Strange ArgumentException in Expression Tree Query Statement
Note: the answer can be in either VB.NET or C#. I have no preference for this Q&A.
I'm trying to distill this rather cumbersome line:
Dim oSession As Session

oSession = Await Me.DbContext.Sessions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(Function(Session) Session.Challenges.Any(Function(Challenge) Not Challenge.Responses.Any))

...into something more readable, like this:
Dim oExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of Session, Boolean))
Dim oSession As Session
Dim oQuery As Func(Of Challenge, Boolean)

oQuery = Function(Challenge) Not Challenge.Responses.Any
oExpression = Function(Session) Session.Challenges.Any(oQuery)
oSession = Await Me.DbContext.Sessions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(oExpression)

...but I'm getting an ArgumentException at the SingleOrDefaultAsync call:

Expression of type 'Func(Of Challenge, Boolean)' cannot be used for parameter of type 'Expression(Of Func(Of Challenge, Boolean))' of method 'Boolean Any(Of Challenge(IQueryable(Of Challenge), Expression(Of Func(Of Challenge,Boolean)))' (Parameter 'arg1')

This also throws when I scale the original call back only a bit:
oSession = Await Instance.Sessions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(Function(Session) Session.Challenges.Any(oQuery))

The strange part is that Session.Challenges.Any is calling for a Func(Of Challenge, Boolean), exactly what I'm declaring: Dim oQuery As Func(Of Challenge, Boolean).
However, it doesn't fail when I do this:
oExpression = Function(Session) Session.Challenges.Any(Function(Challenge) Not Challenge.Responses.Any)
oSession = Await Instance.Sessions.SingleOrDefaultAsync(oExpression)

I'm using the exact syntax in scaffolding the value of oExpression as is used in the long, single-line call. So why is my parameter to that Session.Challenges.Any function causing the scaffolded call to fail? The object typing is correct... what can it be?

If it ain’t broke don’t fix it.

lol  you can say that again

You are trying to use LINQ to Database. LINQ to Database requires using only Expression<> for method parameters so they can be translated to SQL. Your oQuery needs to be Expression(Of Func(Of Challenge, Boolean)). A Func(Of Challenge, Boolean) is compiled code that can't be translated to a e.g. SQL server query. Check your types in the original line of code.

Ah, that makes sense. EF Core can only unwrap the full expression tree when it's scaffolded inside SingleOrDefaultAsync. FYI I get an exception when I try your suggestion: Value of type 'Expression(Of Func(Of Challenge, Boolean))' cannot be converted to 'Func(Of Challenge, Boolean)'. That's OK, though—I'll use the second version above that works.
